# Problema com um algoritmo de busca em um vetor e não encontra

Tags: python, python-3.x

O algoritmo que estou desenvolvendo deve buscar um elementos em um vetor qualquer. O erro acontece quando o elemento não é encontrado.

```
vetor = []

for i in range(1, 5):
    vnum = int(input('Digite um valor: '))
    vetor.append(vnum)
num = int(input("Digite o valor a ser pesquisado: "))

i = 0
achei = False

while i <= 4 and achei == False:
    if num == vetor[i]:
      achei = True
    else:
        i = i + 1
if achei == True:
    print(f'O numero {num} esta na posição {vetor[i]}')
else:
    print(f'O numero {num} não se encontra na lista.')
```

Comment: E qual é o erro?

Comment: Quando é digitado um valor que nao se encontra na lista mostra esse erro:  if num == vetor[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Ao fazer `i in range(1, 5)` você diz que i variará de 1 a 4, pois o 5 não é inclusivo, o que resulta em uma lista de 4 posições, de 0 a 3. No seu laço, você está acessando as posições de 0 a 4, ou seja, a posição 4 nunca existirá na lista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python é muito mais legal, você está programando em C, colega!

Se você quiser verificar a existência ou não de um elemento em uma lista, utilize o seguinte comparador:

```
if num in vetor:
    print("Encontrei!")
else:
    print("Nao encontrei!")
```

Sobre o erro que você está tendo, quando você não encontra i. Você adiciona 4 elementos no seu vetor, vetor[4] não está definido, e sim, vetor[0] até vetor[3]. O seu while está acessando vetor[4]!

Se você quiser manter o seu código, o que eu não recomendo, porque você está inventando a roda

```
while i <= 3 and achei == False:
```

Comment: Obrigado. Ja conhecia o metodo Python de fazer, mas queria fazer na "mao" para saber a logica que existe

Answer (score 3):

As respostas atuais estão corretas e provavelmente eu faria assim mesmo, até por ser mais rápido, mas resolvi responder porque em exercício pode ser que a pessoa tenha que fazer o algoritmo e não usar algo pronto, o que é útil para aprendizado geral e posso mostrar outros elementos da linguagem que poucos conhecem como o `else` do `while`. E também conserto um problema que havia no código e gera erro (o `range()` deveria começar em 0). Não tentei consertar o erro que se a pessoa não digitar um número a aplicação vai quebrar, isto deveria ser tratado em um código válido, e claro, simplifiquei algumas coisas, mas poderia ter usado um `for` no lugar do `while`, preferi deixar como o AP fez. Eu mudei a formação porque o ideone não aceita *f string*. O código estava mais complexo do que deveria, mas [não achei erro](https://ideone.com/kvHz8y) algum além do apontado, dá o resultado correto nos dois casos. Portanto apesar das respostas estarem corretas não resolve o real problema que o AP tinha, apesar de uma resposta ter sido aceita.

```
vetor = []
for i in range(0, 5): vetor.append(int(input('Digite um valor: ')))
num = int(input("Digite o valor a ser pesquisado: "))
i = 0
while i < 5:
    if num == vetor[i]: 
        print("O numero {0} esta na posição {1}".format(num, i + 1))
        break
    i += 1
else:
    print("O numero {0} não se encontra na lista".format(num))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UT8hlN). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/WhileElse). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/WhileElse.py).

Answer (score 2):

Fora a resposta do Maniero, nenhuma retorna o índice onde foi encontrado o elemento no vetor como o autor da pergunta espera, então vou deixar minha colaboração usando o método [`list.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) que retorna o índice do elemento encontrado ou levanta um `ValueError` caso não encontre.

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
num = int(input("Digite o valor a ser pesquisado: "))

try:
    i = lista.index(num)
    print(f'O numero {num} esta na posição {i}')
except ValueError:
    print(f'O numero {num} não se encontra na lista.')
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-387238-6333) com o código funcionando</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
num_procurado = 4

if num_procurado in lista:
    print("Contém")
else:
    print("Não contém")
```

Comment: Oi Johnatan, você poderia explicar o que sua resposta faz?

Comment: Creio que o Johnatan simplificou o maximo possivel para dizer que existe uma forma mais facil de procurar algum elemento dentro de um vetor qualquer. O meu metodo e muito mais complexo e nao é recomendado em Python, pois viola o zen do python em alguns aspectos, mas como eu disse acima: Utilizeia a forma mais complexa para entender a logica de alguns motores de busca simples usando um metodo sequencial.

Comment: Sim, exatamente o que o @FabricioPaiva falou, o Python existem métodos mágicos(simples), que tratam de forma explícita uma forma facilitada de resolver um determinado problema recorrente, trazendo mais produtividade e clareza do código. Explicando o código, declarei uma variável do tipo lista, e passei ela como condição dentro da estrutura de repetição no "if", em leitura simples seria "Se o numero procurado contém na lista."